# How To Use Percent in FlexLayout

Tags: html, css, angular-flex-layout

```
<div id="outer" style="width: 300px; height:300px;">
    <div id="father" style="display:flex; height: 200px;width: 200px;background-color: black;margin-top: 100%;">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
        <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use a FlexLayout in a container,just like the above.
As it see,the fathrer use a percent in margin-top,I consider it will be 200px but 300px in reality.The containing block is the outer.So how do I do can change the flex to a containing block.

Comment: Vertical padding or margin in % use their parents width as reference. Read the specification to find out.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="father" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxFlex="50">
```

**fxFlex** is percent of width and height